# Становление стилей с помощью скриптов

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Хочу сделать сайт для своей школы. У нас там компьютеры древние, как и браузера на них. Компьютеры настолько древние, что браузера даже flexbox не поддерживают.

Я решил, что можно написать скриптик, которые будет делать такие же плюшки, как и flexbox.

Так вот вопрос: насколько это нормально? Можно ли делать такой скрипт или лучше воспользоваться какими-то старыми аналогами?

*Примерные наброски:*

```js
$(function() {
  $('._im-flex').each(function() {
    var pel = 0;
    
    $(this).css('position', 'relative').children().each(function() {
      $(this).css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': pel + 'px'});
      
      pel = pel + $(this).outerWidth();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="_im-flex">
  <div>Текст 1</div>
  <div>Текст 2</div>
  <div>Текст 3</div>
  <div>Текст 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сначала прикиньте целевую аудиторию сайта. Это сайт для сугубо внутреннего использования?

Comment: @AGS17, ну в основном его в школе будут все пользовать

Comment: Для каких целей?

Comment: @AGS17, а есть разница? Информацию там узнать, ну и для общения можно зачудить

Comment: Я бы посоветовал сперва озаботиться обновлением ПО на компьютерах

Comment: Если компы говеные, то и смысла нет перегружать любым `JS` кодом их. Я бы делал наксимально на `CSS`

Comment: Старым браузерам - табличная верстка!

Answer (score 2):

Все задачи, которые возможно сделать флексбоксами, можно решить без них. Хотите облегчить страницы, которые будут запускаться на древних компах с древними браузерами — делайте вёрстку на css, без javascript'овых костылей.

Comment: Не согласен. Каков аналог, например, свойства `order`, без js-совских костылей?

Comment: @Игорь в общем виде его, конечно, нет. но пошаманить можно, например, два блока поменять местами можно при помощи `display: table-footer-group;` и `display: table-header-group;`. вытягивать отрицательными марджинами, позишеном, трансформом и т. д.